# Question about minimal projective presentations of a module.

Tags: representation-theory, modules

I am reading the book [Elements of the Representation Theory of Associative Algebras: Volume 1](http://books.google.com.hk/books?id=SKC79Pt_c9EC&printsec=frontcover&dq=technique+representation+theory+associative+algebras&hl=zh-CN&sa=X&ei=-viFUafnOoXJkgWJp4CoBg&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=technique%20representation%20theory%20associative%20algebras&f=false) .

On page 108, line 11-14, there is a claim:

If $P_0^{t}\to P_1^{t} \to TrM \to 0$ is not a minimal projective presentation, then there exist non-trivial decompositions $P_0^{t}=E_0' \oplus E_0''$, $P_1^{t}=E_1' \oplus E_1''$ and an isomorphism $v: E_0'' \to E_1''$ such that $$ E_0'\oplus E_0'' \overset{\left( \begin{matrix} u & 0 \\ 0 & v \end{matrix} \right) }{\to} E_1' \oplus E_1'' \to M \to 0, $$ where $u: E_0' \to E_1'$ is a homomorpism of left $A$-modules. How to prove this fact? Thank you very much.

I think that if $P_0^{t}\to P_1^{t} \to TrM \to 0$ is not minimal, then the kernel $\ker f$ of $f: P_0^{t} \to P_1^{t}$ is not superfluous. But must $\ker f$ be a direct summand of $P_0^{t}$? If $\ker f$ is a direct summand of $P_0^{t}$, then $P_0^{t} = \ker f \oplus E_0''$ for some $E_0''$. Then we can take $E_0'=\ker f$. Now we know that $TrM$ is not $0$ (Since $M$ is not projective, $Tr M \neq 0$). Therefore $f: P_0^{t} \to P_1^{t}$ is not surjective. Therefore we can take $E_1''=Im f$ and $v = f|_{E_0''}$. Then $v: E_0'' \to E_1''$ is an isomorphism. But can we conclude that $E_1'' = Im f$ is a direct summand of $P_1^{t}$? Thank you very much.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sequence $0\to M^t \to P_0^t \to P_1^t\to Tr(M)\to 0$ is exact as left $A$-modules, in particular, the last 4 terms give a projective presentation of $Tr(M)$.

Suppose $E_0'\to E_1' \to Tr(M)\to 0$ is the minimal projective presentation, so $P_0^t = E_0'\oplus E_0''$ and $P_1^t = E_1'\oplus E_1''$ with $E_i''$ projective.  Next you need to "enlarge" the map $E_0'\to E_1'$ to $P_0^t\to P_1^t$.  There cannot be a map from $E_0'$ to $E_1''$ otherwise the cokernel will not be $Tr(M)$.  There cannot be a map from $E_0''$ to $E_1'$, otherwise it violates minimality.  So now the enalrged map has to be of the form $\begin{pmatrix} u & 0\\ 0 & v\end{pmatrix}$; and you see that $v$ has to be an isomorphism, otherwise the kernel $M^t$ is an decomposable module, contradicting indecomposability of $M$.

Comment: thank you very much. Why if $E_0'\to E_1' \to Tr(M)\to 0$ is the minimal projective presentation, then $P_0^t = E_0'\oplus E_0''$ and $P_1^t = E_1'\oplus E_1''$? Does "There cannot be a map from $E_0'$ to $E_1''$ otherwise the cokernel will not be $M$." mean "There cannot be a map from $E_0'$ to $E_1''$ otherwise the cokernel of $P_0^t \to P_1^t$ will not be $Tr(M)$."?

Comment: I think that we konw $\ker f$ of $f: P_0^t \to P_1^t$ is not superfluous. But how could we conclude that $P_0^t = E_0' \oplus E_0''$ and $P_1^t = E_1' \oplus E_1''$? Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, shoudl be $Tr(M)$, I have edited it now.  For your other question, you know $P_0^t$ and $P_1^t$ are projectives, so they have to be the direct sum of the minimal ones with some other projectives.

Comment: thank you very much. But I still do not understand why $E_0'$ must be a direct summand of $P_0'$. I think that a submodule of a projective module $P$ is not nessisarily a direct summand of $P$ (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/389967/questions-about-projective-modules).

Comment: Say $P_X \to X$ is a projective cover, i.e. the map is minimal (or using your notation: superflous), so for any other surjective map $P \to X$ with $P$ projective, $P$ must contain $P_X$ as a direct summand.  Of course a submodule of projective is rarely projective, but that's not the reasoning we were using.

Comment: thank you very much. I understand why $P_0^t=E_0'\oplus E_0''$ and $P_1^t=E_1'\oplus E_1''$ now. Why if there is a non-trivial map from $E_0'$ to $E_1''$, then the cokernal of $P_0^t \to P_1^t$ will not be  $Tr(M)$? I think that $Tr(M)=E_1' / Im(E_0' \to E_1')$ amd $Tr(M)=(E_1' \oplus E_1'') / Im((E_0'\oplus E_0'') \to (E_1' \oplus E_1''))$.

Comment: If $E_0'$ not isomorphic to $E_1''$, and there is a map $E_0'\to E_1''$, then you get non-trivial cokernel.  If $E_0'$ maps bijectively to $E_1''$, then $E_0'$ cannot maps non-trivially to $E_1'$, contradicting the fact that $E_0'$ is projective cover of $ker(E_0'\to E_1')$ (minimality).

Comment: Have you try with example while you working through the book?  You can always try something on the path algebra of $1\to 2$, or even $1\to 2\to 3$; and I mean do draw all the representations (modules) out. e.g. you have simples: $S_1=(k\to 0), S_2=(0\to k)$, projective: $P_1=(k\to k)$, then you see the projective presentation of $S_1$ is just $S_2\to P_1$ by the combinatorics alone, and you can now check this is a minimal projective presentation, then you can play something more to see what a non-minimal presentation would look like, etc. I always play with examples when I learn from this book

Comment: thank you very much for your help and suggestions.

Comment: @Aaron: could you clarify your explanation 3 comments back? Why couldn't the map $E'_0\to E_1''$ be surjective but not an isomorphism? How does the cokernel of $E'_0\to E''_1$ pertain to that of $E'_0\oplus E''_0 \to E'_1\oplus E''_1$ in this case? And why is the second sentence of your comment true?