# Questions about projective modules.

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $P$ be a projective module and $M$ a submodule of $P$. We know that $M$ is also a projective module. Can we conclude that $P=M\oplus N$ for some module $N$? Thank you very much.

Comment: When you say "$P=M\oplus N$", do you mean "*$P$ is the internal direct sum of* ***sub*** *modules $M$ and $N$*"?, or "*$P$ is isomorphic to $M\oplus N$ for some other module $N$*"?

Comment: @ZevChonoles, thank you very much. I mean "P is the internal direct sum of sub-modules M and N".

Comment: In that case, would $P=\mathbb{Z}$ and $M=2\mathbb{Z}$ provide a counterexample?

Comment: @ZevChonoles, can we conclude that "P is isomorphic to M⊕N for some other module N"?

Comment: I don't think that's true either; I think $P=(2,1+\sqrt{-5})$ should be a projective $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$-module, as is $M=(2)$, but $P\not\cong M\oplus N$ for any other $N$ (that's the part I'm not sure about).

Comment: Rather you want $M$ to be **injective** for it to be a direct summand of any module it embeds in.

Comment: @ZevChonoles : I'm not sure, but why you need it to be internal direct sum? Is it true, in general, that 2Z is not a direct summand of Z? I think, yes. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments that submodules of projective modules are projective does not always hold. If this holds the algebra is called **hereditary**. An equivalent description of that is that $\operatorname{gldim} A \leq 1$.

But even if it holds, this does not guarantee that submodules of projectives are direct summands. For example take the hereditary path algebra of the quiver $1\to 2$. The projective module to the vertex $1$ has the composition series $0\subset S_2\subset P_1$. The simple module $S_2$ is also projective but the module $P_1$ is indecomposable, hence there is no complement.

Comment: Hereditary commutative domains are precisely the Dedekind domains. Take one of them and any proper ideal in it.

Answer (score 2):

This even fails when $P,M$ are free (advice: always check simple special cases before asking!), even when they are of rank $1$. Take any nontrivial principle ideal of an integral domain.